# How do I prove that the integral ${\displaystyle\int_0^1}{\dfrac{\ln(x)}{1-x^2}dx}$ converges?

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, absolute-convergence

How do I prove that the integral ${\displaystyle\int_0^1}{\dfrac{ln(x)}{1-x^2}dx}$ converges?
I tried to find a converging on $[0,1]$ function $g(x)$ such as $g(x) > \dfrac{-ln(x)}{1-x^2}$, but I couldn't succeed in finding it as of yet.

Comment: It does! I did search for similar questions before posting mine but somehow couldn't find anything.

Comment: Found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_0%5E1%5Cfrac%7B%5Cln(x)%7D%7B1-x%5E2%7Ddx%24)